# Input type currency format with comma and decimal place 2

Tags: javascript, format, currency

I just want to ask how to make a JavaScript of currency format of input type text. Is it possible that the numbers will have comma while you type the number? Also, how to make the number fixed with 2 decimal numbers. If I input a 3 decimal placed numbers the last number will round off so it can be 2 decimal.

I have a textbox which accepts numbers only and I want it to automatically convert the numbers into currency format. `1234.556` will be Php `1,234.56`. (Php means Philippine peso)

Here's my input type text:

```
 <input type="text" name='Etxt11' placeholder="Proposed price"  onblur="this.value = 'Php ' + formatNumber(this.value)" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function formatPera(num) {
    var p = num.toFixed(2).split(".");
    return "Php " + p[0].split("").reverse().reduce(function(acc, num, i, orig) {
        return  num + (i && !(i % 3) ? "," : "") + acc;
    }, "") + "." + p[1];
}

var money = 1234.556;
money = formatPera(money);

console.log(money); // Php 1,234.56
```

Also, credit goes to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5342097/1978142

Comment: naks pinoy nag comment... formatPera() method hehe .. thanks :D

Answer (score 8):

maybe like this?

```
var formatNumber = function (val){
    return val.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised this hasn't got more votes.  Concise and works well.