# Currency format regex with 4 decimals that does not show cents if there aren't any

Tags: javascript, string, number-formatting

I am using this regex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24030936/3808307)  but with 4 decimals, as so

```
val.toFixed(4).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
```

but would like the following change.

If the decimals are 0, for example 9.0000, show 9

If it only has 1 or 2 decimal places, show 2 decimal places

9.5000, show 9.50

Else show 4 decimals

Is there a way to do this? Thank you

Comment: hi why not using `Math.fround` then add extra 0 if needed ?

Comment: @Yanis-git in which case?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

**EDITED on user comment remark:**

```js
var val= "9.5493";
if (val.indexOf(".0000")>=0) {
var val = val.replace(".0000", "");
}
if (val.indexOf(".00")>=0) {
var val = val.replace(".00", "");
}

var res = val.split(".");
var1=res[0];
var2=res[1];

if (var2 && var2.indexOf("000")>=0) {
var res = var2.replace("000", "0");
var val = var1+"."+res;
}else{
var val = val;
};


console.log(val);
```

```js
var val= "9.0000";
if (val.indexOf(".0000")>=0) {
var val = val.replace(".0000", "");
}
if (val.indexOf(".00")>=0) {
var val = val.replace(".00", "");
}

var res = val.split(".");
var1=res[0];
var2=res[1];

if (var2 && var2.indexOf("000")>=0) {
var res = var2.replace("000", "0");
var val = var1+"."+res;
}else{
var val = val;
};


console.log(val);
```

```js
var val= "90000";
if (val.indexOf(".0000")>=0) {
var val = val.replace(".0000", "");
}
if (val.indexOf(".00")>=0) {
var val = val.replace(".00", "");
}

var res = val.split(".");
var1=res[0];
var2=res[1];

if (var2 && var2.indexOf("000")>=0) {
var res = var2.replace("000", "0");
var val = var1+"."+res;
}else{
var val = val;
};


console.log(val);
```

```js
var val= "9.5000";
if (val.indexOf(".0000")>=0) {
var val = val.replace(".0000", "");
}
if (val.indexOf(".00")>=0) {
var val = val.replace(".00", "");
}

var res = val.split(".");
var1=res[0];
var2=res[1];

if (var2 && var2.indexOf("000")>=0) {
var res = var2.replace("000", "0");
var val = var1+"."+res;
}else{
var val = val;
};



console.log(val);
```

Comment: I think you missed a dot there val.replace("000", "0"); should be val.replace(".000", "0");

Comment: @user3808307 Nope, that line whill round your 9.5000 case to 9.50, or any other trailing with 000, theirs no dot in it. "9.5000, show 9.50", you can just add another one if you have cases like that. You have not mentioned that in your question.

Comment: then its wrong as it will convert 90000000 to 900000

Comment: @user3808307 you are right, that line need s a bit a work. let me check it.

Comment: @user3808307 Edited, check it. I think all is covered.

Comment: I think you should just declare the var once?